# How to create toggle buttons with react, redux and saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, togglebutton

I am trying to create toggle buttons, using this ToggleButtonGroup https://mui.com/components/toggle-button/

[image]

I do not know how to using it work with react-redux and redux-saga.

Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Your link isn't working, it leads to the homepage of stackblitz.

Comment: You really do not need sagas for a simple toggle button. Also that you want to go with saga is a good indicator that you are currently learning a very outdated style of Redux (saga is nowadays only recommended in very specific scenarios). Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or connect. Please read the official Redux tutorial to get up to speed with modern Redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: @MartinKadlec thank you, I fix the url

Comment: @phry thank you for you comment. I am working in the new project which is quite big and saga was used there That is why if any example to take a look on the flow it will be quite helpful to be able to complete the task.

Comment: @NarekKeshishyan thanks for the link. Can you also provide more context about your app? Do you use hooks or classes? How do you structure your reducers? What do you need to do with the Toggle Button state - just save its state to redux store, or is there some side effect (like fetching some data etc.)?

Comment: @NarekKeshishyan even in a project with saga, you do not use saga for a synchronous task like changing a single value in the store. You dispatch an action to a reducer, that is all that happens